# CUDA: Shared Memory Assignment

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu-shared-memory

Suppose I define a shared variable in a cuda kernel as follows:

```
__shared__ int var;
```

Now, let's say at some point in my kernel I'd like to assign some value, say `100` to `var`. Saying

```
var = 100;
```

results in all threads in the block executing this assignment.

How can I have the assignment take place only once? Is the following my only option?

```
if( threadIdx.x == 0)
    var = 100;
```

Comment: Is there anything wrong with specifying the thread to do the assignment? What sort of alternative were you looking for?

Comment: Perhaps he is afraid of the presence of the `if` statement? I think that it does not penalize the performance in this case. My question is: for the first solution (without the `if` statement), every thread performs a memory write. Does it happen in parallel or the writes are serialized? In other words, which is the most computationally efficient solution?

Comment: @alrikai: No, there's nothing wrong with specifying a particular thread; just thought maybe the compiler (?) would be smart enough to figure out that all threads are doing the same thing and have it done just once. Omitting the thread assignment is just a bit cleaner, semantically.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your only option is actually this:

```
if( threadIdx.x == 0)
    var = 100;

__syncthreads();
```

If you omit a synchronisation barrier, there is no guarantee that *all* threads in the block will read the value of `var` after the assignment statement is executed.

Comment: What happens if you omit the `if` statement but you leave the barrier?

Comment: @JackOLantern: Probably one store attempt to `var` per warp, and every warp stalls at the `bar.sync` instruction until the counter is decremented to zero.

Comment: Do you mean that all the threads in a warp attempt to change the value of `var`? Or only one of the threads is doing the attempt? If so, which one? If all the threads in a warp are trying to store, are the attempts (somehow) serialized?

Comment: @JackOLantern: All of the threads try, but only per warp one will "win" (whether this is serialisation or something else is an opaque implementation detail), and on some architectures not every warp will "win" either.

Comment: And you could assess the "winning" thread by `var = threadId.x` or similar, right? But in principle the option without the `if` statement is "legal" if all the threads write the same value (`var=100;`), the only thing you need being the barrier. If so, perhaps your answer is a bit ambiguous in this respect considering the user's original post...?

Comment: Eh? The question is "How can I have the assignment take place *only once*?" [emphasis mine], and the answer is, conditional assignment + synchronisation.

Comment: You say "Probably one store attempt to `var` per warp" and "All of the threads try, but only per warp one will "win" (whether this is serialisation or something else is an opaque implementation detail)". I would conclude that, due to the "implementation opacity", using the `if` statement _is_ a _sufficient_ condition to have the assignments taking place _only once_, but, depending on what happens under the hood (which at present seems to be not very clear) could not be a _necessary_ condition to achieve that goal. :-)